# Let $A,B,C,D$ be the vertices of a four sided polygon taken in anti clockwise. Given $|AB|=|BC|=3,|AD|=|CD|=4,|BD|=5$ , Find $|AC|$

Tags: geometry

Let $A,B,C,D$ be the vertices of a four sided polygon taken in anti clockwise.

Given $$|AB|=|BC|=3,|AD|=|CD|=4,|BD|=5$$

Find $|AC|$

My try:I have noticed trangles $ABD$ and $BCD$ are right triangles but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: found the symmetry?

Comment: @Exodd Yes I have found that these are similar triangles,further what I should do?

Comment: Similar triangles?

Answer (score 0):

You know the angle $C$ and $A$ are right and $BD$ must be perpendicular to $AC$(since the length of BC and AB are the same). Suppose the intersection point is $M$. Hence you can $AM$ by using BCM is similar to BDC.

Comment: Can you tell me your final answer? so that I compare with my solution.

Comment: @Flip What's your solution?

Comment: I have got the answer $24/5$.Is it correct?Please check it.

Comment: @Flip You are correct. Congratulation!